# Profinet LUA dissector without ports to extract specific bits

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

How can I make a Lua dissector/post-dissector/chained dissector that would get attached under the `PROFINET IO Cyclic Service Data Unit` and for example extract only the last 3 bits of the 5th byte, highlighted in the image below?

All the examples of Lua dissectors I could find are attached to some ports. Profinet does not use TCP/IP layer so there are no ports to attach to.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a small sample capture file somewhere?

Comment: Please let me know when you have the file. I filtered only packages that contained that device MAC address: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PC5jQqL4rXUcqM3VFEonGIuigh6pAHie/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm traveling to [Sharkfest US '22](https://sharkfestus.wireshark.org/index) this week, but I'll try to download the file and take a look at it as soon as I can.  Hopefully then I'll have something to help you with, unless someone beats me to it ...

Comment: I downloaded the capture file, but the "PROFINET IO Cyclic Service Data Unit" is dissected with a lot more information than what your image shows.  What version of Wireshark are you using?  Is it possible that you may only need to update your version of Wireshark to the latest available stable version (currently 3.6.6) to see the information you're seeking and thus avoid the need for a Lua post-dissector altogether?

Comment: Can you check your Wireshark preferences?  If you navigate to *Edit -> Preferences -> Protocols -> PNIO* and select *Enable detailed PROFIsafe dissection*, does Wireshark then show you all the dissected information that you're looking for?  If so, then does that also obviate the need for a Lua post-dissector to dissect the bits you mentioned?

Comment: Yes in your case (and also mine) it's because you most likely have the GSDML-V2.35-Siemens-et200eco-20220106 file to interpret the data AND the startup sequence between the IO Controller and IO Device. There are 2 issues here. 1.- We do not have always the startup sequence available to us. 2- Even if you have it the IO data is still shown under IO Data inside "IODataObject: Slot: 0x1 Subslot: 0x1 ModuleName: "8 DIO DC24V/1.3A 8xM12"" which I still want to dissect. In both cases I still need a dissector to extract these bits one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want using the following example as a rough guide, where I illustrate both how to add the field to the tree as well as to grab the data and do something with it (e.g., append the relevant data to the Info column):

```
local pn_io_post = Proto("PNIOPost", "PNIO Postdissector")

local pf = {
    afield = ProtoField.uint8("pn_io_post.afield", "A Field", base.DEC, nil, 0x03, "A Field Description")
}

pn_io_post.fields = pf

local pn_io_data = Field.new("pn_io")

function pn_io_post.dissector(tvbuf, pinfo, tree)

    local pn_io_post_tree
    local pn_io_data_ex = pn_io_data()

    if pn_io_data_ex ~= nil then
        local pn_io_data_tvb = pn_io_data_ex.range()
        local afield

        pn_io_post_tree = tree:add(pn_io_post, pn_io_data_tvb(0, -1))
        pn_io_post_tree:add(pf.afield, pn_io_data_tvb(4, 1))
        afield = pn_io_data_tvb(4, 1):uint()
        afield = bit.band(0x03, afield)
        pinfo.cols.info:append(" [A Field = " .. afield .. "]")
    end
end

register_postdissector(pn_io_post)
```

Comment: The example works like a charm! Thank you! So then the solution was to use a postdissector, not a standard dissector. I should be able to pick it from here to extract other fields. My next step would be to plot these on a graph with their value on Y axis and time on X axis. I guess I would need to write a Lua tap for that...

Comment: Additionally, if I don't have the Profinet startup sequence, I really need to know what the device does, so I assume the postdissector will be tailored to that specific device, therefore the best way to proceed is to filter the packets capturing only the ones containing the MAC address of that device, to avoid the postdissector extracting wrong values from other Profinet IO devices. This is just me thinking loudly. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad I could be of some help.  

Regarding plotting, you may be able to achieve this using either *Statistics -> I/O Graphs*, adding a graph for the "Display Filter set to `pn_io_post.afield`, "Y Axis" set to **MAX(Y Field)** and Y Field also set to `pn_io_post.afield`.  You may need to reduce the time interval from the default of 1 sec though in order to achieve a better looking graph.

Comment: If that's not sufficient, then you might try using [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) to extract the fields of interest and write them to a .csv file, which you can then import into a spreadsheet and generate a graph from there.  For example:  

`tshark -r file.pcapng -Y "pn_io_post.afield" -T fields -e pn_io_post.afield -e frame.time_relative -E separator=, -E quote=d > file.csv`